# Disabled menu nav item

Tags: angular, typescript

I wanna disable a selected item menu when I click until there is no response. I would to know if there is a generic way to do this.

eg.

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="item.hasSidebar">
      <li [hidden]="itemHidden(item.keyPage) || !item.visible" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" (click)="reloadSidebar(item)" style="cursor: pointer">
            <i class="nav-icon {{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.name | translate}} <i class="nav-change-sidebar fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            <span *ngIf="item.badge" [ngClass]="'badge badge-' + item.badge.variant">{{ item.badge.text }}</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ng-template>
```

The response of each service are inside the components and I can't see from menu component the inside responses.

Comment: Can you add a flow? So when the user clicks on something on the sidebar, it will disable any other clicks until the response come?

Comment: no I wanna disable only the menu clicked

Answer (score 0):

You have to add indicattor flag in component or template accessible service and bind `[disabled]` to that eg

```
<a class="nav-link" [disabled]="inProgress" (click)="reloadSidebar(item)" style="cursor: pointer">
```

and in component

```
inProgress:bool;

reloadSidebar(item){
   inProgress=true;

   ....do the work

   inProgress=false; //probably in async  callback, upon result return

}
```

Comment: ok but my problem is.. how can communicate with single response callback service of each component? (the "do the work" you wrote i mean)

Comment: and there is another error.. Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that is to add a variable `state` (for example) that can have 2 or 3 types (depending on your needs) : `ready`, `loading` and `finish`.

At the beginning the value of `state` will be `ready` and when you will call you function you'll pass it to `loading` and then at the end of your function you'll pass `finish`.

Example :

> example.ts

```
state: 'ready' | 'loading' | 'finish' = 'ready';
…
myFunction(item: any) {
  this.state = 'ready';
  this.myService.anOtherFunction(item).subscribe(() => {
    this.state = 'loading';
    console.log('it is loading time !);
  }
  this.state = 'finish';
  console.log('finished !);
}
```

> example.html

```
<a class="nav-link" [disabled]="state === 'loading'" (click)="myFunction(item)" style="cursor: pointer">
```